# How to Save rounded image in Photos

Tags: ios, swift

I want to save rounded image in Photos Library. I am trying but saved image is not rounded.

```
extension UIImage {
convenience init(view: UIView) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, view.opaque, 0)

    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.init(CGImage: image.CGImage!)
}
}
//calling 
let image = UIImage(view: myView)
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

Comment: What part of this is supposed to make it rounded?

Comment: I am converting UIView into image and than saved it into Photos.
And i want to save rounded image in Photos

Comment: Yes, but have you not written any code for rounding? What have you tried to achieve the rounding effect?

Comment: I tried to make view rounded but didn't get success also I tried using UIBezeirPath but no luck

Comment: you need to make round image in swift only ?

Comment: What I am doing is , first I convert view into image and than save it in Photos. But I need to save rounded image in Photos

Comment: I’m not sure how useful this is going to be. Depending on the device’s camera’s pixel density, the rounding is going to be differently large.

Answer (score 0):

You can only save the picture inside the gallery but you need to make it round after see below code:

Use the following function to make image round.

**In Swift:**

```
func maskRoundedImage(image: UIImage, radius: Float) -> UIImage {
    var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    var layer: CALayer = CALayer()
    layer = imageView.layer

    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(radius)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
    layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    var roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return roundedImage
}
```

**In Objective C:**

```
-(UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(UIImage *) image radius: (float) radius{
    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    imageLayer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;

    imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return roundedImage;
}
```

Following function will return a rounded image, you need to pass `image` and `value` to make it round.

Comment: Yeah see I would agree that this is the best solution, but apparently it is not what OP wants.

Comment: i already tried this but its not working. The saved image in Photos has still not corner radius. :( I want is to save rounded image in Photos

Comment: I think you cant cut the corners of image permanently but using this you can make implicitly, but still you want to go for your gole you need to find some relevant framework for that and tell us also.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your extension:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;
```

You can adjust the value to create different magnitudes of rounding.

Comment: I tried it makes the view rounded but when I saved it into photos , image hasn't rounded or curve

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm trying to see if there is any way of doing the equivalent for a UIImage.